# Optimal bandwidth for a Gaussian filter

Tags: convex-optimization, signal-analysis

I have an $n \times n$ image $A$, and an $m\times m$ image $B$, where $n>m$. As the smaller image looks like a lower-resolution version of the larger one, I'm interested in the relative loss, computed as follows:

- 1. use a Gaussian filter to low-pass $A$
- 2. downsample the filtered $A$ to the size of $B$
- 3. take the difference with $B$.

Specifically, let $f_\sigma$ be the Gaussian filter with bandwidth $\sigma$, and $\Phi(\cdot)$ be the function that downsamples every $n//m$ pixels along row and column. I want to compute
$$\ell_\sigma = \lVert\Phi(f_\sigma \ast A) - B\rVert_F^2.$$

Here $\lVert\cdot\rVert_F$ is the Frobenius norm. $\ast$ is 2D convolution. I use subscript $\sigma$ because obviously the loss value depends on what bandwidth $\sigma$ we adopt.

I calculated the $\ell_\sigma$ for a range of $\sigma$'s. It seems $\ell_\sigma$ is a convex function of $\sigma$. Is that true for every $A$ and $B$? Is it possible to prove it?

Comment: Is $n//m$ supposed to be $n/m$?

Comment: yes, I use the pythonic notation to indicate the rounding operation as necessary. But to simplify, you can assume n/m is an integer.